# Creating a DNS A record

Tags: php, dns

I'm looking into creating a small DynDNS service for my own use but have hit a wall:
Is it possible to create an A record programmatically out of PHP? 
How would I go about approaching this problem?
How do other DynDNS providers solve this problem?

Comment: You need a DNS server to host the A record. How you configure the server depends on which server you use. How you programmatically configure it depends on how you configure it.

Comment: You can host your own DNS server, and provide an API that your PHP can communicate with (Or simply use something like bind, and [programmatically edit your dns config files/reload](https://serverfault.com/questions/903827/how-to-add-a-record-in-bind9).

Answer (score 0):

Well, certainly you can do that. I did that some time ago, with a "similar" objective (it was to create a NIC for a custom TLD).

My approach was to have the names registered in database with all their settings (A, NS, TXT, CNAME...). Then, upon modification, I re-wrote a BIND zone file that I then pointed to from the main BIND domain configuration. After re-writing it, you just have to use `rndc` to reload your zone :

`rndc reload example.com.`

*Note: You can also reload all the zones by not specifying the zone to reload in this command. You also may need the root access, check the security of that, maybe have the command executed by another program that is not exposed to the outside, and strictly limit the root access to only the `rndc` command.*

Of course, that implies your zone is handled by your own DNS server, and not by the one your registrar gives to you. However, some registrars (like OVH) provide an API to directly edit the zone for your record on their DNS servers. This could also be a solution, but it will limit you to their service.

The only thing you have to do for that is to write an algorithm to generate a valid zone file from your stored records (that I think are in some sort of array/object form at one moment). For the SOA record, I would advise you to put it in some sort of template file and then complete with the zone data. [The wikipedia page on the zone file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file) could help you on that.

*Edit note: If you are going for the "programatically write the zone and reload the server" way, I **strongly** advise you to run that part as a CLI script isolated from the outside, that will reload periodically the zone from a database or that will do that on request, and perform checks on what you are writing in your zone. You should not put something that inputs system commands anywhere close to the outside world.*